# R interpreter not found in Zeppelin

Tags: r

I followed the steps outlined here: https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.0/interpreter/r.html

Installed R on the master and verified it is installed as stated in the above URL. Also set the SPARK_HOME env variable and then started Zeppelin. I do not see R in the list of interpreters. In addition, tried %r which failes saying that r interpreter not found.

Any idea anyone?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Zeppelin implementation in HDP 2.4 causes too many conflicts. I am unintalling HDP and going with 2.5 which seems to have a better support for Zeppelin.